# Artifactory::Client Perl module authentication issues

Tags: perl, artifactory

I am trying to use the [`Artifactory::Client`](https://metacpan.org/module/Artifactory::Client) Perl module to deploy artifacts to my Artifactory server.

I am having difficulties trying to authenticate with Artifactory as the `Artifactory::Client` module doesn't seem to allow you to specify your Artifactory login credentials anywhere.

I get an HTTP `403 Forbidden` error message when it makes the HTTP PUT request to try to deploy my artifacts.

I've tried opening up the Perl module and tried to follow the code through the various dependencies to where I think the actual request is being called from, but I can't seem to successfully authenticate with Artifactory.

If anyone has successfully authenticated using credentials, I'd be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: I know nothing about Artifactory, but if all that is required is HTTP Basic Authentication then you could put the necessary information into the URL. For example `http://user:pass@example.com/`. Alternatively you could create a `LWP::UserAgent` object, specify the username and password with the `credentials` method, and pass that object as the `ua` option to `Artifactory::Client->new`.

Comment: Resolved - thanks! I was using the wrong Realm name

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong Realm name – user2402135